# Performance on Java ArrayList vs LinkedList, pertaining to only Creation/Insertion and sorting

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, insert, linked-list

Consider the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class testSortingSpeed {
    public static final int TOTAL_NUMBER = 10000000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Creating ArrayList:");
        List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> a = new ArrayList<>();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_NUMBER; i++) {
            Pair<Integer, Integer> p = new Pair<>(
                (int ) Math.random() * TOTAL_NUMBER,
                (int ) Math.random() * TOTAL_NUMBER);
            a.add(p);
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time Elapsed = " + ((end - start) / 1000.0) + " seconds");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Creating LinkedList:");
        List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> b = new LinkedList<>();
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_NUMBER; i++) {
            Pair<Integer, Integer> p = new Pair<>(
                (int ) Math.random() * TOTAL_NUMBER,
                (int ) Math.random() * TOTAL_NUMBER);
            b.add(p);
        }
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time Elapsed = " + ((end - start) / 1000.0) + " seconds");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Sorting ArrayList:");
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Collections.sort(a, Pair.LEXICOGRAPHIC_ORDER);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time Elapsed = " + ((end - start) / 1000.0) + " seconds");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Sorting LinkedList:");
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Collections.sort(b, Pair.LEXICOGRAPHIC_ORDER);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time Elapsed = " + ((end - start) / 1000.0) + " seconds");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

where Pair is a custom defined data structure.

```
Pair<F, S> { F first; S second; }
```

The output of the above program:
Creating ArrayList:
Time Elapsed = 0.885 seconds

Creating LinkedList:
Time Elapsed = 9.617 seconds

Sorting ArrayList:
Time Elapsed = 0.128 seconds

Sorting LinkedList:
Time Elapsed = 0.351 seconds

I am a bit baffled, cos intuitively, LinkedList creation should be better than ArrayList.

For sorting, that's kinda expected, as it says in api:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html
that Collections.sort
dumps the list to an ArrayList, sort it,
and convert it back to original list type (not sure about this)

and I guess there is probably optimization if the original list type is ArrayList.

Comment: For comparing the complexity of operations in different `List` implementations, [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713144/list-implementations-does-linkedlist-really-perform-so-poorly-vs-arraylist-and) gives you a nice overview. For reliable benchmarks, you should use a proper tool such as [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/), because there are so many [pitfalls](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-benchmarking-2266277.html) that can make a simple "for-loop in `main`" benchmark give undesireable results.

Comment: Also it may be possible (not totally sure) that the JRE unrolls the loop and therefore can create an `ArrayList` of appropiate size from the get-go, which might explain the difference in performance. Keep in mind, that a `LinkedList` needs some kind of `Node` object to wrap around the value. You do not need this for an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Also, the reason why list sorting is so fast may be the _dead-code elimination_ done by the HotSpot VM (see the benchmarking pitfalls link for more details); you're not using the sorted lists for anything.

Comment: It is also important to understand that asking the system for time (via `System.currentTimeMillis()` or `System.nanoTime()`) [is not cheap](http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/nanotrusting-nanotime/).

Answer (score 0):

This will be implementation specific, depending on how ArrayList grows on your platform... But on most platforms, it multiplies its size by a factor of 1.5 every time it's capacity is reached.

Here's the code from JDK 1.8:

```
/**
 * Increases the capacity to ensure that it can hold at least the
 * number of elements specified by the minimum capacity argument.
 *
 * @param minCapacity the desired minimum capacity
 */
private void grow(int minCapacity) {
    // overflow-conscious code
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
    if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
        newCapacity = minCapacity;
    if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
        newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
    // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
    elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
}
```

This method will be called 36 times if you're adding ten million objects into an empty ArrayList, which has a default initial capacity of 10. I've done some profiling on grow() and Arrays.copyOf(), and they're very fast, even for large arrays.

LinkedList, on the other hand, needs to allocate a new Node object for every element added to it--ten million times. That's why LinkedList is slower in this case. It's *much* faster when you need to insert or remove elements somewhere near the beginning or middle of the list.