# ArrayList or Linked List - Which collection to use if both insertion/deletion and look up operation is to be performed

Tags: java, arraylist

As we know, Linked List is for fast insertion deletion
Array List is for fast look up

I have requirement of 10000 records to be saved in List. Which collection I would use.
Both lookup and insertion / deletion operation may be performed on that list.

Which Collection do I use and the reason why?
Or
Would i use my own created collection ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656471/performance-differences-between-arraylist-and-linkedlist

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734705/which-one-runs-faster-arraylist-or-linkedlist

Comment: Your first sentence is a huge oversimplification. We can't tell without knowing what you're really doing in the code. For most of the use-cases, an ArrayList is the right choice.

Answer (score 2):

**INSERT**

`LinkedList`

Insert first - O(1)

Insert last - O(1)

Insert anywhere - O(n) - it's because need to find by index where to insert.

`ArrayList`

Insert first - O(n)

Insert last - O(1)

Insert anywhere - O(n)

---

So `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` have the same O(n) insert anywhere.

**DELETE**

`LinkedList`

Delete first - O(1)

Delete last - O(1)

Delete anywhere - O(n) - And again it's because need to find by index where to delete.

`ArrayList`

Delete first - O(n)

Delete last - O(1)

Delete anywhere - O(n)

So `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` have the same O(n) delete anywhere.

---

As you can see insert and delete anywhere for both is the same.
If you always do insert last operation then ArrayList is suitable to use because if you know the index then lookup is O(1) and O(n) for LinkedList. I think you need to find the golden middle what is more suitable to use.

Also if you dont care about dublicate-free you can use HashSet. It's based on hash table and provides suitable performence (O(1), O(log(n) for many cases) for insert and delete, lookup.

HashSet jdoc

> This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size), assuming the hash function disperses the elements >properly among the buckets.

Comment: Hashmaps/hashsets: O(1) for remove/update/insert is on average where m=n(If the number of buckets=m and number of elements = n). Worst case complexity is O(logn) , since Java 8 due to balaned trees under a hash-bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Check these tables at the link below everytime you need to choose a data structure that fits to your problem. 
[BIG-O Complextity](http://bigocheatsheet.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your data, and unless your use-case involves a lot of insertions and deletions using a [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) (= the way to get `O(1)` insertions and deletions on `LinkedList` when not operating at either end), real-world performance will favor `ArrayList` due to lower overhead and less pointer dereferencing.

Factors that will be important in your choice:

1. What is in your lists? If your lists are collections of small objects (say, `Integer`), then overhead from `LinkedList` will be more noticeable. Each node in a `LinkedList` needs at least 2 extra pointers, for an estimated overhead of ~8 bytes per node. More memory means more cache misses and lower performance.
2. How exactly will you insert and delete? If you only insert and delete at the end of the list, then `ArrayList` is the way to go. If you insert and delete in random locations, then ArrayList is still probably the way to go (because of faster scans). Only if you need to insert at the start, and/or make consistent use of `ListIterator` will you actually see a performance benefit from `LinkedList`.
3. How unordered will your list be, and how often will you need to perform full scans? While in theory all memory accesses take the same time, it is quicker to iterate through elements that are next to each other in RAM (due to processor caches) than to jump all over the place.

Finally - have you considered using a `Set` or `Map` to speed up search and access? O(n) list access sums up quickly, specially if you use it from within loops. Maps and Sets can provide `O(log n)` and `O(1)` access (depending on implementation), for noticeable performance improvements.

Some references:

- [Performance on Java ArrayList vs LinkedList, pertaining to only Creation/Insertion and sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29584600/performance-on-java-arraylist-vs-linkedlist-pertaining-to-only-creation-inserti)
- [Why is processing a sorted array slower than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023988/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-slower-than-an-unsorted-array) (c# but applicable to Java)
- https://github.com/joaquintides/usingstdcpp2015/blob/master/Mind%20the%20cache.pdf (c++ but list vs vector discussion applicable to Java -- in a LinkedList vs array sort of way)